# use xpath to extract value from xml file with multiple namespace in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to extract node value with multiple namespaces in java but not succeed. The xml file is like:

```
<ns26:start xmlns:ns26="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/capture/start"  
            xmlns:ns31="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/filters"            
            xmlns:ns13="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/monitoredObjects"  
            xmlns:ns6="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa"  
            xmlns:ns10="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/monNodeObjects" 
            xmlns:ns7="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/capture/monitoredElements" 
            xmlns:ns11="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/pointcodes" 
            xmlns:ns8="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/capture/captureSession" 
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/sessionSaveInfo" 
            xmlns:ns4="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/customData" 
            xmlns:ns3="http://www.tektronix.com/iris/isa/manifest">
    <ns6:Id>LAB:11300/isaclient;440</ns6:Id>
</ns26:start>
```

I want to extract Id with xpath `local-name()`. Expression like `//*[local-name()='start']/*[local-name()='Id']` but didn't get any matched node. Please help to find issue here. Thanks

Add the java code here:

```
public static List<String> getXPathValueNamespace(String xml, String expression throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException 
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder builder;

    Document doc = null;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

    doc = builder.parse(source);

    // Create XPathFactory object
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    // Create XPath object
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
        list.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `//*[local-name()='start']/*[local-name()='Id']` works and for the example document one node should be contained in the result node list.

But you should use `nodes.item(i).getTextContent()` to retrieve the node content, since `getNodeValue()` returns `null`  for element nodes.

Comment: yes, this is what I am doing exactly but without success. Even I changed expression to //*[local-name()='start'], still couldn't find the node.

Comment: @KevinChen your original expression did not contain the stars. Anyway - the expression works, so there must be something else going wrong - maybe there is a bug in your code when you run the xpath?

Comment: I posted the java code in the original post. Thanks

Comment: Good catch, but the nodes.length() return 0. No matching nodes. So there are no nodes to iterate.

Comment: @KevinChen I ran your example locally and had no problems. Just used an 'InputSource` pointing to a local file and the constant expression from the question. So there is something other going wrong. Good luck